# How to use a scaling border-image without ever beeing behind the actual content of the bordered element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give some textbox an svg border-image that is able to scale vertically (when the text get's longer or zoomed) without ever overlapping it's content. It should also be able to get squished horizontally when viewed on a small screen.  I don't want to give my four borders fixed pixel widths since the size of the border image should depend on the size of the content only to distort the border as little as possible.

The border should look like this:
[image: border]

I'm trying to make it work using border-image-* properties, but if I don't give fixed (huge) border widths the border starts to creep behind it's content when the content takes up a certain amount of space.

```css
.element {
    border-style: solid;
    border-image-slice: 27% 10.5% 32% 14.3% fill; /* sliced accurately by percent, meaning the content should have always at least this distance from the edges of the image relative to the size of the image*/
    border-width: 27px 10.5px 32px 14.3px; /* since this is scaled by border-image-outset i thought  i could put the relative scalars here to make that easier */
    border-image-source: url('./img/Box1.svg');
    border-image-repeat: round;
    border-image-width: 27% 10.5% 32% 14.3%; /* the proportional scaling of the slices */
    border-image-outset: 2 9 2 9; /* fiddeling with these to get the border away from the content but it doesn't really work */
}
```

Thank's in advance!

PS: If you wanna fiddle with it: https://jsfiddle.net/v25cxtjs/4/

Comment: Can you put your HTML code?

Comment: @Iman I added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v25cxtjs/4/) you can just paste more lorem ipsum and you'll see how the border is behind it's content.

Comment: One thing you could do is make sure the outer div is bigger than the content, and then place it in the center of the outer div

Comment: @Robo yes but i would have to make it bigger by a fixed amount, atleast vertically right? horizontally i could just do that with padding and percentages but vertically?

Comment: No use if `width` is 1px and `height` is 1000px, nothing will be readable

Comment: @Robo I don't really understand, if u view it on a 1px wide screen nothing will be readable anyway.

Comment: I'm talking about the outer div and not the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240681/discussion-between-jakob-and-robo).